# Importing iTunes Music Library in Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, music, metadata

I have a extensive music library in iTunes on my Mac. I have found a dozen import scripts to import the metadata (ratings, play count) to Rhythmbox. But the comments I have found all indicate that they do not work very well, and none of them are in active development/have had any fixes to them after being initially dumped on the Web. Considering that this is something a user/developer only has to do once

Does anyone have experience with importing an iTunes library in Rhythmbox? Any importer scripts that can be recommended?

Also, I do not understand how these scripts are supposed to import the music itself. The directory structures and paths will be different, for example, and they do not seem to address that.

The scripts I’ve seen are [itunes2rhythm](http://code.google.com/p/itunes2rhythm/source/browse/trunk/itunes2rhythm.py) and [itunes-to-rhythmbox-ratings](http://code.google.com/p/itunes-to-rhythmbox-ratings/downloads/detail?name=transferRatings-0.8.1.py&can=2&q=).

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and wrote [migrate-itunes-to-rhythmbox](https://github.com/phauer/migrate-itunes-to-rhythmbox). It will convert your playlists, play counts and ratings to Rhythmbox. It was written in 2016 and tested with iTunes 12.5.1 and Rhythmbox 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [iTunesToRhythm](http://www.esanbock.com/iTunesToRhythm/iTunesToRhythm.html)

The code has been maintained in 2014. According to the website it also supports Amorak and Windows media player. There is an extensive description on the website. I tried it myself and it worked well.